# Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\RakController::update(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected

Tags: php, database, laravel

I've got an error that says :

> Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\RakController::update(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected

Here's the codes that I have :

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $data=Rak::find($id);
    $data->kode_rak=$request->get('kode_rak');
    $data->server=$request->get('server');
    $data->os=$request->get('os');
    $data->ip=$request->get('ip');
    $data->masa_berlaku=$request->get('masa_berlaku');
    $data->merek=$request->get('merek');
    $data->type=$request->get('type');
    $data->save();
    return redirect ('/d_rak');
}
```

And this is the overall preview :
[image]

What did I miss here, any help is appreciated

Comment: try `$data->update();` instead

Comment: show us your form too

Comment: The update function seems to be in your controller and with the $id variable, you should have one route parameter (like {id} in your route) to be given to this function. Check your route rule or include it in your question so people can answer you.

Comment: Can you share your target route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could skip the `$id` parameter, and get it inside the controller using the `$request` parameter :

```php
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->id;
    $data=Rak::find($id);
    $data->kode_rak=$request->get('kode_rak');
    $data->server=$request->get('server');
    $data->os=$request->get('os');
    $data->ip=$request->get('ip');
    $data->masa_berlaku=$request->get('masa_berlaku');
    $data->merek=$request->get('merek');
    $data->type=$request->get('type');
    $data->save();
    return redirect ('/d_rak');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try 1:

Check The Used Class must be `Illuminate\Http\Request;`

Try 2 : Helper Request Function :

```
public function update($id)
{
    $data=Rak::find($id);

    $data->kode_rak = Request()->get('kode_rak');
    $data->server = Request()->get('server');
    $data->os = Request()->get('os');
    $data->ip = Request()->get('ip');
    $data->masa_berlaku = Request()->get('masa_berlaku');
    $data->merek = Request()->get('merek');
    $data->type = Request()->get('type');

    $data->save();
    return redirect('/d_rak');
}
```

And if it **didn't work** 
print `func_get_args()` in update function for see your passed args

Comment: Where do you use this method? In routing or in another method in the controller

Answer (score 0):

Check your URL 
example:

```
http://{yourdomain}/update/{your_id}
```

in POST ROUTE.
And if {ID} isn't required then define it as not required arrgument as,

```
public function update(Request $request, $id="")
{
    $data=Rak::find($id);
    $data->kode_rak=$request->get('kode_rak');
    $data->server=$request->get('server');
    $data->os=$request->get('os');
    //your code
```

This will solve your few arguments error for update method.